# Android app killed after returning from Unity module

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, signals

I am currently working on an Android app, where I am using an Unity module. I applied everything according to this tutorial:

https://medium.com/@davidbeloosesky/embedded-unity-within-android-app-7061f4f473a

and it launches perfectly. But I have a problem, when I am closing this Unity module. I get the following errors:

```
 11-02 [...] I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 9290 SIG: 9
```

or

```
 11-02 [...] I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 9518 SIG: 9
```

When I launch the Unity module I also get the following

```
 11-02 [...] E/Unity: Unable to find AudioPluginOculusSpatializer
 11-02 [...] E/Unity: Unable to find libAudioPluginOculusSpatializer
```

but I don't think, that this is the issue, because this module runs fine even with these errors.

Do you have any ideas, what may cause these errors (maybe there is some internal problem with Unity compiler)? Is there any way, in which I can get some more information about these errors?